# How can I attach some data to a row in a tableView - Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a `tableView`, and I am adding rows to it from different sources.  Using the original widget library I was able to attach data to the `insertRow` method, but since upgrading to 2.0 that now seems impossible.

How I think I should be able to attach data:

```
list:insertRow{                     
    rowHeight=rowHeight,
    isCategory=isCategory,
    rowColor=rowColor,
    lineColor=lineColor,
    data=data[i]
}
```

`data` should then be accessible inside the touch event:

```
local function onRowTouch( event )
    print( event.target.data )
end
```

Since widget2.0 this is not the case.  My question is this: how can I access that data?

NB: In other parts of the app I have been able to reference the original data table by using the row index as the table key, eg: `print( data[event.row.index] )`, but I cannot do this on a table with multiple data sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an undocumented way of passing data to the table row.  I'm placing it here in case anyone finds this thread who is having the same issue.  As it is undocumented it may be liable to change at any point.

You can attach data using the following:
`list._view._rows[#list._view._rows].data = data`

`data` can be anything, and this works in the same way as adding it into the `insertRow` method.

To access this data in the touch method it would simply be: `event.target.data`

Comment: Any data structure in the tableView with an underscore is for internal use and should not be relied upon.  The engineers understand you need access to the rows.  So use that with caution.

Comment: So what would be the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this is to use the index value on the row and inside the onRowRender function you reference your data table:

```
local function onRowRender(event)
     id = event.index
     print(data[id])
end

list:insertRow{                     
    rowHeight=rowHeight,
    isCategory=isCategory,
    rowColor=rowColor,
    lineColor=lineColor,
}
```

With the index value you can fetch whatever you need from your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob, but this is what I am referring to in the NB at the foot of the question.  I'm pulling in data from various sources and I am using categories throughout the table (which count as an indices).  As such the index never matches the row.  Example: If I have 3 arrays/table which populate the list, each with categories dotted throughout, how would I know what `id` is referring to?  Which table?  It would also get confused with category headings.  Looking on the Corona forums I'm not the only person with this issue.

Comment: No doubt adding categories messes up straight indexing.  You should be able to set additional parameters in the list like:

list:insertRow{                     
    rowHeight=rowHeight,
    isCategory=isCategory,
    rowColor=rowColor,
    lineColor=lineColor,
    id = idOffRowInYourDataTable
}

Then in your onRowRender, id should be an available property to the event table in addition to the .index property.